# How to configure IntelliJ to show SVN as a repository option alongside GIT, Mercurial, etc?

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, version-control, repository

I had a project I am working on running on IntelliJ and connected to SVN. However when I opened IntelliJ today it wasn't connected. So I tried to enable version control from VCS but the SVN option isn't there, or in checkout from version control or import into version control.

I checked if Subversion plugin was enabled in the settings and it was, what's the problem?

[image: Plugins]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Marketplace** tab shows plugins available in the repository. So it looks like the plugin is installed, but not enabled.

Switch to the **Installed** tab, and make sure the plugin is enabled.